# How can I use a result from a SQL-statement in second SQL-statement? | PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi**, to everyone who reads this, 
I've trying to read out a **UserId** from my MySql Database.
I want to use the result in the next SQL statement which should
add the `Id` into another table. The problem is I've no idea how to do that.

Here I've tried to select the row **"UserId"** from my **`accounts`** table.

***Code looks like this:***

```
//first statement
$SqlLookStm = ("SELECT UserId FROM accounts WHERE UserName = ?");
$initLStm = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($initLStm, $SqlLookStm)) {
    header('Location: ../signup.php?error=SqlError');
    exit();

} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($initLStm, "s", $UserName);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($initLStm);
}
```

**$UserName** is a value out of a form.

Now I want to use the userid, which should be the result from the first statement,
in my next SQL statement, which should add the `id` from the user in the
**"account_session"** table under the row **"account_id"**.

***Code looks so:***

```
//second statement
$SqlInsertIdStm = ("INSERT INTO account_session (account_id) VALUES (?)");
$initIIStm = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($initIIStm, $SqlInsertIdStm)) {
   header('Location: ../signup.php?error=SqlError');
   exit();

} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($initIIStm, "s", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($initIIStm);
}
```

But how can I use the result from statement one so that I can insert it as the 
**$id** string in the second statement?

I've been trying this now for four days... (╯°□°）╯︵ **┻━┻**
Thanks to everyone who can help me.

Comment: Where do you fetch the data from the first statement and put the value in `$id`

Comment: Nowhere. Exactly that is my problem. I've no idea how to fetch the data and put the value in `$id`. That's what I'm trying.

Comment: Have a look at php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php - especially Example #2 Procedural style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the id as an integer like this

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($initIIStm, "d", $UserId);
```

And then execute the statement
(i recomend you to use lower case character for first character of string)

EDIT: when I wrote the comment, I was thinking about the printf() function that needs %d to print decimal values, instead of 'd' use 'i'

Comment: Why would you like to use a `double` for a user ID?

Comment: [php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_param](https://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_param#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters) says that `d` is for binding `double` types. I had to look up the function to be sure of that. One would use `i` for integer types. (I just realized that [`printf()`](https://php.net/printf) in PHP uses `%d` for integers, so I can see where the confusion would come from.)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mean 'i'. When i wrote the comment I was thinking about printf() function that needs %d, my mistake 

Answer (score 0):

MySQL single query answer:

```
INSERT INTO `account_session` (account_id) SELECT `UserId` FROM `accounts` WHERE `UserName` = ?
```

To do this with PHP and MySQLi I would recommend using an Object Orientated approach, thus:

```
$myOwnSql = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `account_session` (account_id) SELECT `UserId` FROM `accounts` WHERE `UserName` = ?";

/***
 * Prepare the SQL statement
 ***/
$stmt = $myOwnSql->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $UserName);

/***
 * Execute the prepared statement 
 ***/
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->affected_rows < 1){
    /***
     * Nothing effected, something went wrong.
     ***/
    error_log("SQL Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    header('Location: ../signup.php?error=SqlError');
    exit;
}
/***
 * close statement and connection 
 ***/
$stmt->close();
```

---

## How to extract data from the database using MySQLi Object Orientated (OO):

```
$myOwnSqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

/***
 * Assume we have this table and it is suitably populated  
 ***/
$query = "SELECT UserId, RealName FROM accounts WHERE UserName = ?";

$stmt = $myOwnSqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $UserName);
$stmt->execute();

/***
 * Bind result variables 
 ***/
$stmt->bind_result($userId, $humanName);

/***
 * fetch each found row of bound values 
 ***/
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        print "Name: ".$humanName."<BR>";
 }

 /***
  * close statement 
  ***/
 $stmt->close();


/***
 * close DB connection 
 ***/
$myOwnSqli->close();
```

---

## [Read The Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

---

**To solve your specific issue with the code you have (ie not to rework your current code) please view and show us your `error_log` file generated by PHP / MySQL.**

Thanks.